# How to remove characters before a specific character?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

I want get the most specific from the current url in visual basic .net.
I've tried several code but it just was the same.

I have this code:

```
Dim CurrentURL1 As String = Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

The code will result like: /FolderName/CurrentUrl.aspx

What I want is, just get the 'CurrentUrl.aspx'.

How to get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried Path.GetFilename ? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Actually, I think you can use the Uri class, the class is better suited for your needs. It has several properties you can use to get what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried by injecting that code. So it resulted like: `Dim CurrentURL1 As String = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.PathAndQuery)` ... Thanks :)